# javascript - How to get a specific form from a forms array without knowing the number of forms in the page

Tags: javascript, html, forms

I have an html page with multiple forms:

```
forms1
forms2
forms3
forms4
.
.
.
formsn
```

In JavaScript we know we can deal with a specific form by the forms array:

```
document.forms[2]
```

But how can I get the `n` form without knowing the number of forms?

Something like that:

```
n = numbnerOfForms
document.forms[n]
document.forms[n-1]
```

Comment: `document.forms[document.forms.length - 1]` ?

Comment: try using document.forms.length

Comment: wouldnt it be better to get a form by a unique attribute like id?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that `document.form.length` is what you want. It returns the length of an array; in this case the form array.

NOTE: if and array is:

```
a ['q','w','e','r','t','y']
```

array.lenght return 6, this is useful when you nedd to cicle via for an array

```
for (var i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
  // ...
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Since `document.forms` is an array you can call `.length` on it

```
n = document.forms.length;
document.forms[n-1] //last form in the array
document.forms[0] //first form in the array
```

Answer (score 0):

`document.forms` is an [array](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array), it has a `length` attribute:

```
var n = document.forms.length;
// ...
```

Answer (score 0):

use `document.forms.length` to get form length. you can get nth form using `document.forms[document.forms.length-1]`